# How can i use named queries in JPA without having to list the entity in persistence.xml?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jpa, openjpa

I am able to retrieve and persist an Entity with*out* listing it in `persistence.xml`, but if I want to use a `@NamedQuery`, it doesn't work unless I list it in `persistence.xml`. Is there a way around this?

I am using Tomcat 8 with OpenJPA 2.4.2.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
        version="2.1"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <!-- Used for persisting events, authentication pieces -->
    <persistence-unit name="PushPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <!-- Use Apache's OpenJPA -->
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>

        <!-- Our backing store is our data source from context.xml -->
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/webservice</non-jta-data-source>

        <!--
            Without this, I can load and persist the entity but 
            CANNOT use Named Queries                        
        -->
        <class>push.authentication.AuthCredentials</class>

        <!-- Don't require listing the managed classes here -->
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="true"/>
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72, PrintParameters=true, MaxActive=10, MaxIdle=5, MinIdle=2, MaxWait=60000"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!-- Tell Maven what language version to use -->
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Enables the annotations, etc needed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.exterprise</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Our jersey libs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CDI to JAX-RS Binding -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish/jersey-gf-cdi-ban-custom-hk2-binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-gf-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.servlet/weld-servlet-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld/weld-core-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <!-- We don't use the version number in the war file name -->
        <finalName>MyProj</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <!-- Enhances the JPA classes -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>JPA Enhance</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>**/push/*.class</includes>
                            <persistenceXmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml</persistenceXmlFile>
                            <toolProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>addDefaultConstructor</name>
                                    <value>false</value>
                                </property>
                                <property>
                                    <name>enforcePropertyRestrictions</name>
                                    <value>true</value>
                                </property>
                            </toolProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Class declaration of named query:

```
package push;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@NamedQueries(
    {
        @NamedQuery(
            name = "Users.findByName",
            query = "SELECT ac FROM Users ac WHERE ac.userName = :userName"
        )
    }
)
@Table(name = "PushClient")
public class Users
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the EntityManager Interface and it says it throws IllegalArgumentException if a query has not been defined with the given name or if the query string is found to be invalid or if the query result is found to not be assignable to the specified type and if get IllegalArgumentException based on your snippet of code I think the third one is your case, try to use

```
EntityManager.createNamedQuery(java.lang.String name);
```

instead of

```
EntityManager.createNamedQuery(java.lang.String name,
                               java.lang.Class<T> resultClass);
```

And see if you get the same result or not